# Amazon EC2 and RDS accross AWS Accounts

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I am trying to setup EC2 access to an RDS instance.

First I want to upload a backup created on the EC2 instance.

When I connect to the instance on local machine, I can connect with `mysql -h instance.us-west-1.rds.amazon.com -u <user> -p`
but when I attmept to connect from the EC2 instance I am met with a `ERROR 2003`

I believe it to be a firewall problem, but I am having trouble adding the security group of my instance to the RDS DB Scecurity Group.

`Invalid security group , groupId=, groupName= <group_name>. (Service: AmazonRDS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValue; Request ID: 8180a717-xxxx-xxxx6-xxxx-fxxxxxxxxx)`

I notice the `groupId=` is empty and wonder if that could be the cause of the problem, but there is no field for it in the console.

The EC2 instnace belongs to another AWS account.

Thanks.

Comment: review the forum https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=49600

Comment: Thanks for the reference @KuldeepPhPDeveloper